# Two edge routers in VRRP with multiple upstream providers?

Tags: vrrp

Assume I have two routers in a VRRP setup R1, and R2.  Also, assume I have three WAN providers W1, W2 and W3, each of which has given us a P2P /30 and /64.  (Of course, they'll all be different)

R1 would have W1, W2, and W3, R2 would have what?  It can't have W1, W2, and W3 because those belong to R1 right?  I'd need W1-2, W2-2 and W3-2 right?  Unless the providers also support VRRP in which case I'm just using their VRRP VIP, I'd need a lot of IP addresses?

Do I have this right?  For the three providers W1, W2, and W3, each of which has unique P2P addresses to transit our BGP-managed space, how do I set up the VRRP between our routers R1 and R2?  Someone also suggested this is the wrong way to do it, and I'm better off just having the two edge routers do eBGP?

Comment: No, VRRP is to fool LAN hosts into thinking that there is one gateway. The VRRP needs to run on a common network with the routers and LAN hosts. What you describe is not that. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64697/8499).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clear on what you’re going trying to accomplish. Are you protecting against a WAN failure? A router failure? An ISP failure?  All of the above? Can you operate with just two or one circuit operational?

When you understand your requirements, then you can design the network to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

VRRP creates a virtual router backed by at least two physical routers. If you want to connect each WAN link, you'll need a virtual router group for each of those links.

Connecting both routers to each WAN link requires some way of sharing the connections - either two handover ports, a network switch/VLAN for an Ethernet handover, or something similar. DSL cannot be directly shared, so it might require additional hardware.

The ISPs don't necessarily need to know about this as each only sees the virtual router.

If you use BGP to advertise your network to the ISPs, that should provide a better and easier way of route failover. Then you'd just use VRRP towards the routers' LAN side.